# Css: List on Multiple Divs

Tags: html, css

I have unordered list in two divs

**HTML**

```
<div class="wee">
<ul>
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Ball</li>
<li>Apples</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="wee">
<ul>
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Ball</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wee{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgba(176,137,138,1.00);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

My problem is that i could not align them straight.

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mdkh7uf/)

It's a same on me that I could not figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:top;` to **.wee** should do it:

```
.wee {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgba(176,137,138,1.00);
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/9mdkh7uf/1/)**